# difference between literal types and variable types in c++

Tags: c++, c

I was studying C++ via cplusplus.com and came across something like `75u`, which seems to describe an unsigned constant.

What has got me confused is: what's the point of declaring a constant to be unsigned when there is  already  a provision to declare the variable to which `75` will be assigned as unsigned?

#### Simpler said:

Why would you specifically add a `u` to a number when assigning it to (for example) an unsigned int?

What's the difference between

```
unsigned int i = 75;
```

and

```
unsigned int i = 75u;
```

Comment: Example use case: Suppose you wanted a large number (that can't be stored in int). You could append u to make sure it's not default converted to int first, and thus avoid an overflow (you'd get a negative int without the u).

Answer (score 8):

That's because the type of the variable (in an assignment) on the left hand side of the `=` has *nothing* to do with how an expression is evaluated (the right hand side).

This seems to surprise many new programmers, but it's still true.

Something like this:

```
const float two_thirds = 2 / 3;  /* Bad code! */
```

does *not* assign 0.6666667 to `two_thirds`; since both `2` and `3` are `int` literals, the expression is evaluated using integer math.

You need:

```
const float two_thirds = 2.f / 3;
```

to force the expression to `float`. Similar reasoning applies to the use of `unsigned`, since it has larger range than signed variables.